# Calculating magnitude of a complex fraction

Tags: complex-numbers

I am having a hard time determining the magnitude of a complex fraction.

$$G(j\omega) = \frac{\omega^{2}_{n}}{j\omega(j\omega + 2\zeta \omega_{n})}$$

I understand that $$|G(j\omega)| = \sqrt{Re\{G(j\omega)\}^{2}+Im\{ G(j\omega)\}^{2}}$$

How would I break $G(j\omega)$ up into real and imaginary parts

Update:

$ \omega_{n}, \zeta$ are pure values

$j$ is an imaginary number

$\omega$ is the independent variable

Comment: Is $j$ the symbol you're using to designate $\sqrt -1$? (In math it's usually $i$, but I've seen physicists and engineers use $j$.)

Comment: I'd also guess that  $\omega$, $\omega_n$, and $\zeta$ are all pure real values, but you need to say that explicitly.

Comment: @JonathanZ I think $\omega$ is more often used to represent a cube root of unity (though I can't be sure what OP means).

Comment: Oh yeah, that's possible too. I was guessing that this was a model for a Green's function for some physical system. But it will certainly make the answer different depending on which it is. I guess we just have to wait for @user3067059 to update.

Comment: I think it is a (continuous) Fourier transform for some signal $f(t)$. $\omega_n$ is a frequency and $\zeta$ is the damping ratio, so they are real numbers. It is common routine to get the Magnitude and "Phase" of $G(j\omega)$.

Comment: @Poypoyan you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $\omega, \omega_n,\zeta \in \mathbb{R}$, and using that $\,|z|^2 = z \cdot \bar z\,$:

$$
\big|G(j\omega)\big|^2 = \frac{\omega^{2}_{n}}{j\omega(j\omega + 2\zeta \omega_{n})} \cdot \frac{\omega^{2}_{n}}{-j\omega(-j\omega + 2\zeta \omega_{n})} = \frac{\omega_n^{\,4}}{\omega^2 \left(4 \zeta^2\omega_n^{\,2}+\omega^2\right)}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Use conjugation $$G^*(j\omega) =G(-j\omega)$$
( assuming everything except $j$ is real )

Then 
$$ Re(G(j\omega))= \frac 12(G(j\omega)+G(-j\omega))
\\  Im(G(j\omega))= \frac 1{2j}(G(j\omega)-G(-j\omega))
 $$

Answer (score 0):

Are you required to approach the problem by finding the real and imaginary parts? It's probably easier to use the following properties of complex magnitude:$$ |ab| = |a| \cdot |b|$$ and $$\left|\dfrac{a}{b}\right| = \dfrac{|a|}{|b|}$$